# Strange reviews of my tag wiki edit

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently I've been editing some tag wikis.

On my edit for the `for loop` tag I've had two people say that I'm "Trying to promote product or service or being deliberately destructive".

Why am I getting these reviews? Is that the reviewers haven't read the post or is it something I've done wrong?

[image]

If you actually read the post you'll see I've tried to improve the tag wiki, this may or may not be a good edit, but I'm certainly not trying to deliberately vandalize the tag.

Comment: I suspect those two reviewers didn't realise this was a tag wiki edit..

Comment: I do see other problems with the edit: tag wikis are meant to explain how the tag should be used on this site, and you are describing `for` loops as they are implemented in C-like languages; the tag applies to a far wider range of programming languages than just that (Python `for` loops are `for each` loops and have no initialisation, condition and increment components, only an iterator).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/: *Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.*

Comment: That said, one of these reviewers was clearly robo-reviewing (rejecting *everything*) and they have received a manual review ban because of this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, next time I'll make it clear that its a tag wiki edit and I'll make my edits more related to how the tag is used rather than the concept of the tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The review actions are simply wrong. One of these reviewers was robo-reviewing, rejecting *everything in sight*. They have received a manual review ban. I'm not sure why the other reviewer rejected it for the reason stated, perhaps they thought they were looking at a question or answer edit.

That said, I do see other problems with the edit: tag wikis are meant to explain how the tag should be used on this site. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/

> Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.

A `for` loop is not really that specialised.

Also, you are describing `for` loops as they are implemented in C-like languages, but tag applies to a far wider range of programming languages than just that. In Python, for instance, `for` loops are `for each` loops and have no initialisation, condition and increment components, only an iterator. Yet there are [4.5k questions tagged with both `python` and `for-loop`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%20for-loop?mode=all).

Comment: "One of these reviewers was robo-reviewing, rejecting *everything in sight*" **PSA on behalf of Meta:** What we meant by begging robo-reviewers to stop blindly approving everything was that robo-reviewing is detrimental to Stack Overflow, not that blindly rejecting everything is OK. Sorry for the confusion.